# several type for a template parameter

Tags: c++

I search a tips where i could have several types for a template parameter, for example:

That is my class:

```
template <class T, class U = unsigned char>
class Value
{
    private:
          T value;
          U mask;
    public:
          Value(T inValue, U inMask) : value(inValue), size(inMask){};
          // ...
};
```

That is my functions:

```
void process(Value<int, ..>); // process(Value<int, {unsigned char, unsigned short}>)
void process(Value<float, ...>);
```

And I would like that example works :

```
int main()
{
  Value<int> vl1(16, 0x80); 
  Value<int, unsigned short> vl2(16, 0x8000);
  Value<float> vl3(0.85, 0x80);

  process(vl1); // call process(Value<int, ...>)
  process(vl2); // Call process(Value<int, ...>)
  process(vl3); // Call process<Value<float>)
}
```

And avoid to template my process functions, like that:

```
template<class U> void process(Value<int, U>);
template<class U> void process(Value<float, U>);
```

Comment: Could you explain why you want to avoid function templates? As far as I can see, that's the only option.

Comment: Yes because my function is in class which is herited by few child classes and i would like simplify the code with the templates.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to provide default value for your `process` function

```
template<class U> void process(Value<int, U>);
template<class U> void process(Value<float, U>);
```

is enough.

Comment: yes, it is true, i edit my code but i want to know if i can avoid to template my process function or to find an alternative method.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid templates for one of the cases that they were created for?

Comment: Because i have a function by type but i can have many masks(unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned int) and my function is in a abstract class which is herited by several child classes. I called many time my process, function(hundred sevral time).

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a non-template function accept unrelated types, that's what templates are for.

What you can do is make your template function declarations a bit shorter:

```
template<class U> void process(Value<int, U>);
template<class U> void process(Value<float, U>);
```

The default argument isn't necessary as `U` will be deduced from the arguments you pass in anyway.